# Grouping in MongoDB and adding to Group

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I have a `MeterReadings` collection that looks like the following.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fc768b33561870a262813c6"),
        "installedAppId" : "A",
        "readings" : [
                {
                        "n" : "daf43d66-6c3b-4553-80af-6a0b1cf97418:power",
                        "t" : 1606902984662,
                        "u" : "W",
                        "v" : 100
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fc768c73561870a262813c7"),
        "installedAppId" : "B",
        "readings" : [
                {
                        "n" : "daf43d66-6c3b-4553-80af-6a0b1cf97418:power",
                        "t" : 1606902984662,
                        "u" : "W",
                        "v" : 200
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fc768e43561870a262813c8"),
        "installedAppId" : "A",
        "readings" : [
                {
                        "n" : "daf43d66-6c3b-4553-80af-6a0b1cf97418:power",
                        "t" : 1606902984672,
                        "u" : "W",
                        "v" : 300
                }
        ]
}
```

My desired output is to group by `installedAppId` and then have each `readings` in one entry attached to it from all the matching `installedAppId`'s. Shown below is what I am aiming for.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fc768b33561870a262813c6"),
        "installedAppId" : "A",
         "readings" : [
                {
                        "n" : "daf43d66-6c3b-4553-80af-6a0b1cf97418:power",
                        "t" : 1606902984662,
                        "u" : "W",
                        "v" : 100
                },{
                        "n" : "daf43d66-6c3b-4553-80af-6a0b1cf97418:power",
                        "t" : 1606902984672,
                        "u" : "W",
                        "v" : 300
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fc768c73561870a262813c7"),
        "installedAppId" : "B",
        "readings" : [
                {
                        "n" : "daf43d66-6c3b-4553-80af-6a0b1cf97418:power",
                        "t" : 1606902984662,
                        "u" : "W",
                        "v" : 200
                }
        ]

}
```

Grouping by `installedAppId` does return two groups using the data above.

```
> db.MeterReadings.aggregate([ {$group: {_id: {installedAppId: "$installedAppId"}}} ])
{ "_id" : { "installedAppId" : "B" } }
{ "_id" : { "installedAppId" : "A" } }
```

As each reading is different though adding `readings` as another entry in `$group` is the same as just querying the entire database.

```
> db.MeterReadings.aggregate([ {$group: {_id: {installedAppId: "$installedAppId", readings: "$readings"}}} ]).pretty()
{
        "_id" : {
                "installedAppId" : "A",
                "readings" : [
                        {
                                "n" : "daf43d66-6c3b-4553-80af-6a0b1cf97418:power",
                                "t" : 1606902984672,
                                "u" : "W",
                                "v" : 10.2
                        }
                ]
        }
}
{
        "_id" : {
                "installedAppId" : "B",
                "readings" : [
                        {
                                "n" : "daf43d66-6c3b-4553-80af-6a0b1cf97418:power",
                                "t" : 1606902984662,
                                "u" : "W",
                                "v" : 10.2
                        }
                ]
        }
}
{
        "_id" : {
                "installedAppId" : "A",
                "readings" : [
                        {
                                "n" : "daf43d66-6c3b-4553-80af-6a0b1cf97418:power",
                                "t" : 1606902984662,
                                "u" : "W",
                                "v" : 10.2
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `$push` or `$addToSet` seems to do the trick, adds arrays however for each. Would be nicer if could just push to one array.

## addToSet

```
> db.MeterReadings.aggregate([{$group : {_id : "$installedAppId", readings: {$addToSet : "$readings"}}}]).pretty()
{
        "_id" : "B",
        "readings" : [
                [
                        {
                                "n" : "daf43d66-6c3b-4553-80af-6a0b1cf97418:power",
                                "t" : 1606902984672,
                                "u" : "W",
                                "v" : 200
                        }
                ]
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "A",
        "readings" : [
                [
                        {
                                "n" : "daf43d66-6c3b-4553-80af-6a0b1cf97418:power",
                                "t" : 1606902984672,
                                "u" : "W",
                                "v" : 300
                        }
                ],
                [
                        {
                                "n" : "daf43d66-6c3b-4553-80af-6a0b1cf97418:power",
                                "t" : 1606902984672,
                                "u" : "W",
                                "v" : 100
                        }
                ]
        ]
}
```

## push

```
> db.MeterReadings.aggregate([{$group : {_id : "$installedAppId", readings: {$push: "$readings"}}}]).pretty()
{
        "_id" : "B",
        "readings" : [
                [
                        {
                                "n" : "daf43d66-6c3b-4553-80af-6a0b1cf97418:power",
                                "t" : 1606902984672,
                                "u" : "W",
                                "v" : 200
                        }
                ]
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "A",
        "readings" : [
                [
                        {
                                "n" : "daf43d66-6c3b-4553-80af-6a0b1cf97418:power",
                                "t" : 1606902984672,
                                "u" : "W",
                                "v" : 100
                        }
                ],
                [
                        {
                                "n" : "daf43d66-6c3b-4553-80af-6a0b1cf97418:power",
                                "t" : 1606902984672,
                                "u" : "W",
                                "v" : 300
                        }
                ]
        ]
}
```